# Rails: Form with Select and 2 .where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to check if a campaign has the correct brand and if the campaign is active (valid_until is a Date-Record). The entry inside the record should only appear if both conditions are true.

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
<% Brand.all.each do |b| %>
 <%= f.collection_select(:campaign, Campaign.where(brand: b.company).where(:valid_until < Date.now), :campaign, :campaign, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting these errors:

> syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')' ...ompany).where(:valid_until Date.now), :campaign, :campaign, ... ... ^

and

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...true}, {class: 'form-control'}) );@output_buffer.safe_append... ... ^

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Campaign.where(brand: b.company).where('valid_until < ?', Time.now)
```

Or:

```
Campaign.where('brand = ? and valid_until < ?', b.company, Time.now)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error (with the first solution): `undefined method now for Date:Class`  Any ideas?

Comment: @Harakiri he used that because that was in your code example.  I assume you want `Date.today`.  If you were using times you'd want `Time.now` or `Time.zone.now`

Comment: Yep, have not noticed

Comment: Ah, sorry guys. `Date.today` did it. I set valid_until to "2016-01-10" but this is smaller then Date.today, nevertheless it appears in the dropdown. Do you know why? The record should only be shown if valid_until is earlier (smaller) than Date.today.

Comment: Edit: The record shows only up if I set valid_until to a Date PAST or at  Date.today and not BEFORE Date.today. Strange..